# AWS Elastic Beanstalk launching into default VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to launch a Tomcat Beanstalk Instance into my VPC. But for some reason, the Instance does not consider my Configuration Template.

What I have done :

1. Created a VPC in a separate script and manually launched the requested instance and connected to it via SSH

Problem 1:  If I use cloud-formation for some reason the script (below) creates a new stack for the Beanstalk

Problem 2:  Upon successful launch, the beanstalk is created into the default VPC or crashes if I delete the default VPC.

How can I debug this? 
Why is this happening, since I pass the correct parameters to the script?

```
  SampleApplication:
    Type: 'AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application'
    Properties:
      ApplicationName: !Ref ApplicationName
      Description: OCAP's AWS Elastic Beanstalk Sample Application

  SampleApplicationVersion:
    Type: 'AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ApplicationVersion'
    Properties:
      Description: Version 1.0
      ApplicationName: !Ref SampleApplication
      SourceBundle:
        S3Bucket: !Ref AppS3Bucket
        S3Key: !Ref AppS3Key

  SampleIdentityEnvironment:
    Type: 'AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment'
    Properties:
      ApplicationName: !Ref SampleApplication
      EnvironmentName : OCAPSampleIdentityManager
      VersionLabel: !Ref SampleApplicationVersion
      SolutionStackName: !FindInMap [ StackMap, !Ref StackType, stackName ]
    DependsOn:
      - ConfigurationTemplate
      - SampleApplicationVersion
```

ConfigurationTemplate:

```
Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ConfigurationTemplate
Properties:
  ApplicationName: !Ref SampleApplication
  Description: 64bit Amazon Linux running Tomcat 7
  SolutionStackName: !FindInMap [ StackMap, !Ref StackType, stackName ]
  OptionSettings:

    - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
      OptionName: EC2KeyName
      Value: !Ref KeyName

    - Namespace: aws:ec2:vpc
      OptionName: VPCId
      Value : vpc-0123456789

    - Namespace: 'aws:ec2:vpc'
      OptionName: Subnets
      Value: subnet-0123456789, subnet-0123456789

    - Namespace: 'aws:ec2:vpc'
      OptionName: ELBSubnets
      Value: subnet-0123456789, subnet-0123456789

    - Namespace: 'aws:ec2:vpc'
      OptionName: AssociatePublicIpAddress
      Value: 'true'
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved Problem 2 :
You need to have this defined in "SampleIdentityEnvironment:"

```
TemplateName: !Ref ConfigurationTemplate
```